# How to debug grails runtime exception?

Tags: java, groovy, noclassdeffounderror, grails

I have a grails project and a java project. The java project was a standalone set of POJO classes, and I just dumped them into src/java under my grails project.

In the controller, I added an import statement for this package.

Now when I do a grails run-app and try to run the program, I get a grails runtime exception. It is saying NoClassDefFound for a class that is in a package that one of my POJOs imports.

The error message is showing on a line of my Controller, but the class that is missing is from an external jar that my POJO needed. I moved the .jar that it is complaining about to the grails project's lib folder. What else do I need to do?

How do I track down what is really causing this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I would first try a grails clean... then grails run-app after you moved the jar to the lib folder

Comment: is there anything that i can change in the environment that would be causing the symptoms?

Comment: Are you running on Tomcat? Does your app server complain about loading the JAR file at all? Sometimes if there is something wrong with a jar, the container won't load it. Turn up the logging level and see if you see anything like "jar not loaded".

Comment: This is just using Jetty or wahtever runs when I do a grail run-app, not tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a low-level approach: run [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (which now integrates the formerly separate File Monitor). With it you can see what class file the JVM is searching for.

Also, you can add -verbose:class to the JAVA_OPTS defined in startGrails/startGrails.bat in the bin directory of grails. This will show the output (verbose!) from the class loader.

Possibly there are other JARs that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this jar file as a dependency to BuildConfig.groovy?
Let Grails handle all dependencies.